# Anylogic Boarding Delays & Queues

Tags: simulation, anylogic

I'm trying to do a boarding simulation with agents & the process modelling library in Anylogic. The model should be somewhat like the aircraft boarding examples from the Anylogic cloud, just with a seating scenario for an event-location: https://cloud.anylogic.com/model/db46dc3e-af22-46f0-a1fc-2df5506fe1d1?mode=SETTINGS&tab=GENERAL

So far i've been creating agents with their seat number assigned as an attribute (from an excel file). A "move to" block moves the agents on paths to the right seat(point node). Everything is working fine until there.

[for testing, i only built some seats, but the model should get bigger.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yjtaS.png)

[process so far. delay_seating is not working. seat is set to delay until stopDelay(), so the agents stay in their seat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NishI.png)

Now the agents should have a delay before they sit down and i also need the agents to queue, if one of them is sitting down. As i'm only able to assign one agentLocation in the delay & queue block, i'm a bit clueless about how to do this, as i would have to assign a lot of point nodes / paths or so.
Of course, i could just build the process for every seat, but i'm pretty sure, there's a better solution.

Would be highly appreciated if anyone had a tip for me!

Thanks,
Lucas

Comment: There is, but you need to study some basic AnyLogic concepts such as accessing agent properties from flow chart blocks. Do all (!) the step-by-step tutorials in the help first, they cover a ton of this stuff https://anylogic.help/tutorials/index.html